# Why changing copy of pointer does not affect the initial object

Tags: pointers, go

I learn to handle pointers,
in this example I don't understand why
reassign i3 to a new current object and do the action current = current.next does not affect the i3 object. However, the same address is used

```
func main() {

        i := &Node{data: 1}
        i2 := &Node{data: 2, next: i}
        i3 := &Node{data: 3, next: i2}

        current := i3
        for current.next != nil {
                current = current.next
        }
        log.Println(current)
        log.Println(i3)
        /*
        2020/06/03 12:19:23 &{1 <nil>}
        2020/06/03 12:19:23 &{3 0xc42000e1f0}
        */

}

type Node struct {
        data int 
        next *Node
}
```

whereas if I don't use a copy of the i3 object, the object is well modified in the loop

```
func main() {

        i := &Node{data: 1}
        i2 := &Node{data: 2, next: i}
        i3 := &Node{data: 3, next: i2}

        log.Println(i3)
        /*
                2020/06/03 12:22:05 &{3 0xc42000e1f0}
        */
        for i3.next != nil {
                i3 = i3.next
        }
        log.Println(i3)
        /*
                2020/06/03 12:22:05 &{1 <nil>}
        */

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current` and `i3` both are pointers.

```
current:= i3
```

Copy a pointer means now `current` will point the same address where `i3` point.

A copy of a pointer doesn't any relation with which it was copied only both point the same value. So modifying `current` doesn't any effect on `i3`.

You can do that using this way

```
current := &i3
for (*current).next != nil {
    *current = (*current).next
}
```

Now `current` is a pointer of `i3`, now if you change the current pointed value that will affect `i3`.

Answer (score 2):

In your first example the short variable declaration:

```
current := i3
```

Creates a new variable named `current` of pointer type. It is a distinct variable than `i3`, but it has the same pointer value.

The loop only modifies (assigns to) the `current` variable, so the pointer stored in `i3` never changes. So after the loop `i3` still points to the node with `data = 3`, and `current` will be the last, that is with `data = 1`.

In your second example you don't create a `current` variable but you modify (assign to) the `i3` variable. So after the loop it will point to the last node with `data = 1`. The node objects are not modified in either case, just the `current` or `i3` variables.

Answer (score 1):

In the first example, you create a pointer `current` which will have the same value what `i3` have (The address of the struct `Node{data: 3, next: i2}`).

When you execute the `current = current.next` statement in the for loop, you only change the value of the pointer and not the value behind the address. You only replace the stored address in the pointer.

If you follow the iterations:

```
0., current -> Node{data: 3, next: i2}     
1., current -> Node{data: 2, next: i}     
2., current -> Node{data: 1}
```

The other pointers will remain the same.

```
i -> Node{data: 1}      
i2 -> Node{data: 2, next: i}     
i3 -> Node{data: 3, next: i2}
```

In the second case, you do the very same, but instead of the `current` pointer, now you change the address stored in the `i3` pointer.
If you follow the iterations:

```
0., i3 -> Node{data: 3, next: i2}     
1., i3 -> Node{data: 2, next: i}     
2., i3 -> Node{data: 1}
```

The other pointers will remain the same.

```
i -> Node{data: 1}      
i2 -> Node{data: 2, next: i}
```

And of course you will have an object somewhere in the memory without access to it (Node{data: 3, next: i2})